# Flask redirect without url params

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I have 2 flask app, client and server respectively
And I wanna download some files from server by redirecting user directly to the server
So basically I want redirect to this route:

```
@app.route('/api/1.0/conf/<token>', methods=['GET'])
def returnPeerConf(token):
    if token is valid:
        return file
```

So I'm write client like this:

```
@app.route("/downloadConf/<token>", methods=["GET"])
def downloadConf(token):
    url = f"http://{ipAddress}/api/1.0/conf/{token}"
    redir = redirect(url)
    return redir
```

I wanna get url like: `http://ipAddress/api/1.0/conf/myGreatToken`
But get: `http://ipAddress/api/1.0/conf/%7B'token':%20'myGreatToken'%7D`

And this doesn't work.
How to redirect without params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like token is a dict value. Perhaps you could try getting the value for `token['token']` and then add it to the url, instead of putting the entire `token` dict in.

For example:

```py
app.route("/downloadConf/<token>", methods=["GET"])
def downloadConf(token):
    token_val = token['token']
    url = f"http://{ipAddress}/api/1.0/conf/{token_val}"
    redir = redirect(url)
    return redir
```

Comment: yeah you right
Programming is difficult...

Comment: Did this solve the issue for you?

Comment: This is a good answer, actually if you are wondering `%7B'token':%20'myGreatToken'%7D` is urlencoded value of `{'token': 'myGreatToken'}` which is a dictionary,

Answer (score 0):

Try using urllib.parse module quote() function.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote